# itunes Connect test flight beta - no app for download

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

I have an app in iTunes connect that I'm beta testing with external users. Some invited testers are not seeing any app available for download in iTunes connect. What could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this where iTunesConnect shows the user has not accepted the invite to join (I don't know whether the user did not, or that ITC has the user in the wrong state). It seems that they still get the messages about new builds, but can't install them. I found that I could not re-invite them, even removing and adding their email did not help. The only way I found to fix it was to add a new alternative email address for those users.

**Update**
I have now seen myself why gmail addresses are a particular problem. Opening an invite email in the gmail app and clicking the link does not work. Even if TestFlight is installed it only shows the app briefly and then redirects to the app store. If you open the email in the Mail app instead then when you click the invite link it opens in TestFlight and asks you to install the app as expected.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that one of my testers already had testflight installed. He tried uninstalling and then re-accepting the invite but no luck. Maybe I'll have him uninstall and try another email.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit... if you are seeing the same thing as me than ITC shows the user as not having accepted the invite.

Comment: I am seeing them as invited and not accepted! Interesting, I'll ask for different emails. Maybe this is a coincidence, but all of my beta testers with Gmail addresses have been having problems. No problems yet from non-gmail users. Hahaha

Comment: Thanks for your help! It also does appear that gmail addresses, in particular, are having trouble... iOS vs Android war? haha